# Why is Heroku running a webpack process when I am using express.js?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, webpack

I uninstalled webpack and removed the `webpack.config.js` file so that I could use `express.js` with Heroku. After committing and pushing to heroku, my log reads like this:

```
$ heroku logs
2017-09-10T17:42:43.224045+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-09-10T17:42:02.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-09-10T17:42:47.480825+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js`
2017-09-10T17:42:50.050087+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:471
2017-09-10T17:42:50.050108+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2017-09-10T17:42:50.050108+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2017-09-10T17:42:50.050109+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-09-10T17:42:50.050110+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js'
```

The starting process in the log is trying to initiate webpack ^, but in my Procfile I have this:

```
web: node server.js
```

To confirm that, here is `heroku ps`

```
$ heroku ps
=== web (Free): node server.js (1)
web.1: up 2017/09/10 14:41:56 -0400 (~ 27m ago)
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "youtube-instant-search",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Renders youtube videos after keystrokes",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "git@github.com:mattwarren10/youtube-instant-
search.git",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^5.8.29",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "browserify": "^14.4.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "eslint": "^4.6.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react-addons-create-fragment": "^0.14.17",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "express": "^4.15.4",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-intl": "^2.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.0.4",
    "youtube-api-search": "0.0.5"
  }
}
```

server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));
app.use("/style", express.static(__dirname));

// viewed at based directory http://localhost:8080/
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Does it take time for heroku to update? What's going on?

Comment: Do you have `package-lock.json` or `npm-shrinkwrap.json` in the root project directory?

Comment: Yes already there. Found the problem. I was looking at the wrong time heroku started the process. This is the correct time:

`2017-09-10T19:20:26.896929+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command node server.js`